# What is the value of integral $\ln x$?

Tags: integration, logarithms

What is the value of integral $\ln x$? Example:

$$\int_2^4 \left(5x^4+2x+5+2\ln x +{1\over x}\right)\,dx$$

Comment: have you tried wikipedia?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_logarithmic_functions

Comment: I can't find it on wikipedia

Comment: i just posted a link as comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is an antiderivative of $\ln(x)$. It is
$$
\int \ln(x) \; dx = x\ln(x) -x +C.
$$

This should allow you do find the integral.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use integration by parts.

Another hint is greyed out below (hover over the box to show it, but only after you've tried!)

> $\displaystyle \int \ln x\, dx = \int (1 \times \ln x)\, dx$